# NoClassDefFoundError when I create mock for method with parameters

Tags: java, android, mockito, junit3

I have the following class:

```
public class SomeClass {

    private int digit;

    public SomeClass(int i){
        digit = i;
    }       
    public int someMethod(int i){
        /*
         * Some work
         */
    }    
    /**
     * Other method
     */
}
```

And when I want to create a spy of this class with [Mockito](http://mockito.org/), I get java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

But when I change method to

```
public int someMethod(){
    // some work
}
```

all works without an error. What am I doing wrong?
My test class:

```
@PrepareForTest ({SomeClass.class})
public class SomeClassTest extends AndroidTestCase {

    private SomeClass someClass = null;

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        // This is necessary on devices in order to avoid bugs with instantiation order
        System.setProperty("dexmaker.dexcache", getContext().getCacheDir().getPath());

        SomeClass localSomeClass = new SomeClass(10);
        someClass = Mockito.spy(localSomeClass);
        Mockito.doReturn(5).when(someClass).someMethod();
    }

    @Override
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
    }

    public void testCorrectExemption(){
        /**
         * Test code
         */
    }
}
```

**Edit:** stacktrace with exception

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.mockito.internal.matchers.Equals
    at org.mockito.internal.invocation.ArgumentsProcessor.argumentsToMatchers(ArgumentsProcessor.java:47)
    at org.mockito.internal.invocation.InvocationMatcher.<init>(InvocationMatcher.java:34)
    at org.mockito.internal.invocation.MatchersBinder.bindMatchers(MatchersBinder.java:26)
    at org.mockito.internal.handler.MockHandlerImpl.handle(MockHandlerImpl.java:50)
    at org.mockito.internal.handler.NullResultGuardian.handle(NullResultGuardian.java:29)
    at org.mockito.internal.handler.InvocationNotifierHandler.handle(InvocationNotifierHandler.java:38)
    at com.google.dexmaker.mockito.InvocationHandlerAdapter.invoke(InvocationHandlerAdapter.java:49)
    at SomeClass_Proxy.testMethod(SomeClass_Proxy.generated)
    at ru.test.SomeClassTest.setUp(SomeClassTest.java:47)
    at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:190)
    at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:175)
    at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
    at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1661)
```

Comment: At what line is the exception thrown?

Comment: Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: Exception throws on `Mockito.doReturn(5).when(someClass).someMethod();`  stacktrace will later

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the problem by replacing `mockito-core.jar` with `mockito-all.jar`

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it has anything to do with mock. NoClassDefFoundError error is coming because your SomeClass.class is not in class path  during execution. Put it class path and error will go away.